# Simulink adding blocks

Tags: matlab, block, simulink

Trying to use simulink but have some problems:

```
part.type = 'PB1';
part.name = ['SLibrary/PB_1_' int2str(rjoint1Count) '_Default/PB1_1' ];
part.handle = add_block(pjnt11, [sys '/' part.name], 'Position', pos, 'MakeNameUnique', 'on');
```

where

```
pjnt11 = 'SLibrary/PB_1_Default/PB1_1 ';
sys=Robot
```

which are defined before. Also the predefined `SLibrary/PB_1_Default/PB1_1`is
[image] and [image]

When I run the code I got the following error:

```
Error using startSimulation (line 134)
A new block named 'Robot/SLibrary/PB_1_1_Default/PB1_1' cannot be added
```

Tried to find it online but couldn't find any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a block, giving it the same name as an existing block.  Block's must have unique names.

Comment: Use of the 'MakeNameUnique' flag should create a new block but change the number at the end of the dest block name to make it unique.